# in QGIS version 2.18.0, can we save queries for further usage on other data sets

Tags: query

In QGIS version 2.18.0, using Query Builder on attribute data, can we save the defined Query for further usage on other shp files with attributes.

I tried selecting a layer> properties> query builder . wrote simple query for finding out name of cities beginning with "B"and it gave query results. I wanted to further save this query for future usage, but could not find an option in the Query builder.

I am looking for LOAD Query and SAVE query buttons in the query builder dialogue box. This functionality was available in earlier versions of QGIS.

Comment: What have you tried, what did work. Please edit the question to add these details

Comment: The query builder in the Layer Properties filter section is different from the selection query dialog box.  You can save and load from the latter, perhaps that is what you recall?